# DataTables ajax advanced search

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I request assistance or an example of performing an advanced AJAX search using DataTables.

I have several form fields that I want to use as filters.

We want to perform server-side filtering and pagination for performance reasons.

When the page loads for the very first time, we don't want it to search for anything.

Users will need to click on some button to initiate a search, but it needs to work also for sorting and searching.

I have tried using the documentations recommendation for "retrieve" set to true, and "deferRender" set to true, but this does not seem to work.

My code looks similar to this:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';

function initTable() {
    return $('#results-table').DataTable({
        retrieve: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        deferRender: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '/home/filter',
            type: 'POST',
            data: function(d) {
                d.form = $('#form').serialize();
            }
        }
    });
}

initTable();

$('#form').on('submit', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const table = initTable();
    table.ajax.reload();
});
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to 86 the datatables implementation in favor of NonFactors MVC Grid.

Sorry, no answer, but no one responded.